# Are Maran Ovadiah Yosef's lectures translated?

Tags: translation, hacham-ovadia-yosef

Where can I find English transcribed lectures of Maran Ovadiah Yosef, if such a thing exists?

I've come across some clips of his lectures on YouTube that have Hebrew transcriptions and sometimes English too, so maybe the same exists for longer lectures?

Comment: Perhaps commentary on Avot